# Probability Density of the Sum of Two Un-identical Uniform Random Variables

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, convolution

> Let $X$ ~ Uniform$[a,b]$ and $Y$ ~ Uniform$[c,d],$ where  $a\le b\le c\le d.$  Find the probability density of $Z = X + Y.$

I know I have to use the convolution formula

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(z-y)f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy.$$

However, I am struggling to find the region I must integrate over. I know for $z \le a+c$ and $z \gt b+d$ that $f_Z(z) = 0.$ But for the middle terms I do not know what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It may be worth also breaking the integration at $z=a+d$ and at $z=b+c$ (which might be in either order)

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you explain what you might mean by "middle terms"?  The region of integration is *always* the entire set of real numbers; *there are no exceptions.*  In this case you perform the integration by recognizing that $f_X$ is *zero* outside the interval $[a,b]$ and $f_Y$ is zero outside $[c,d].$

Comment: BTW, if you would draw a picture of the support of $(X,Y)$ and some contour lines of the function $X+Y,$ you can (literally) read the answer off that diagram. No calculation (not even any algebra) is needed at all.

Answer (score 4):

**Plot the contours (level curves) of the function $(x,y)\to x+y$ over the support of this distribution.**

Here, to illustrate, is such a diagram with $(a,b)=(0,2)$ and $(c,d)=(3,4):$

[image]

The value of $z=x+y$ ranges from $a+c$ to $b+d$ as you sweep from the lower left to upper right (the direction given by the vector $(1,1),$ since $x+y = (x,y)\cdot (1,1)^\prime$).  As it does so, since the distribution of $(x,y)$ is uniform, *the lengths of the contours are proportional to the probability density of $z.$*

The diagram makes it clear that those lengths:

- (Region I) Increase linearly from $0$ as $z$ goes from $a+c$ (in the lower left corner) to $a+d$ (in the upper left corner),
- (Region II) then remain constant as $z$ goes from $a+d$ to $b+c,$
- (Region III) then decrease linearly to $0$ until $z$ reaches $b+d$ (in the upper right corner).

This description would change slightly were the rectangle vertically oriented (the order of $a+d$ and $b+c$ gets reversed), but the pattern remains the same.  Consequently, *$z$ has a trapezoidal distribution* and we can plot its density function without further ado:

[image]

We don't need to label the vertical axis because the total area must be $1.$  In this diagram that implies the height of the trapezoid is $1/(b-a).$ You can easily write down equations for the five parts of this graph (over the intervals delimited by $-\infty, a+b, a+d, b+c, b+d,$ and $+\infty$) from this information.

This graphical solution will guide you in articulating a formal answer in terms of integrals.